# TikZ: explicitly-named node in a matrix offers anchors in the wrong place

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

I have put `\node` commands inside a TikZ `matrix of nodes`. I am aware that this breaks automatic `m-1-1` node naming, but when I give the name of a node explicitly, the anchors are in the wrong place.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (foo) 
{
    \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*}; & \\
    \node[varname] {height}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    \node[varname] {weight}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
};
\node[vartype] {Foo} [above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I am aware that I don't need the `\node` commands in this example, but the above code is placeholder -- the full code requires nontrivial drawing within some matrix cells.)

The `Foo` node appears in the middle of the matrix instead of above it:

[image]

The `(age)` node is being referenced in `\node[vartype] {Foo} [above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west];` and all my experiments to refer to `somethingelse.west` have failed to compile.

Why is the `Foo` node appearing in the middle of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the order of label and braces a little bit. By the way i prefer the node name  from 57.1 Matrices of Nodes [Tikz Manual](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (auto).

Modifications:

```
\matrix (foo) [struct]
```

instead of

```
\matrix[struct] (foo)
```

and

```
\node[vartype,above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west] {Foo};
```

replaces

```
\node[vartype] {Foo} [above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west];
```

.

Example image:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (foo) [struct]  
{
    \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*}; & \\
    \node[varname] {height}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    \node[varname] {weight}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
};
\node[vartype,above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west] {Foo};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

First question. You can use explicit names and automatic names together in a matrix of nodes. The syntax is explained in page 646. `|(age)|` will apply name `age` to the node replacing the automatic name. All other nodes will keep their automatic names.

In fact the pair `|...|` is used to particularly change node attributes. Inside bars you use `[...]` for options and `(...)` for node name. As an example, `|[blue](age)|` would define a node to be drawn with blue color and named `age`.

Second question: loose of anchors. Anchors are correct, but your syntax not.

You wrote

```
\node[vartype] {Foo} [above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west];
```

and everything behind node contents is ignored. (Try the same line with `;%` behind `{Foo}`)

This was the mistake.

You should write all options, together or not, with node's name o not, but all of them before node's text:

```
\node[vartype] (fooo) [above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west] {Foo};

\node[vartype, above=2ex of age.west,anchor=west] {Foo};
```

Both work.

Following code shows how to type your example with a `matrix of nodes` (without `\node...`). One node is labelled  `age` and all others follow `foo-xx-xx`. And as an example of names mixture a line is drawn between `(age)` and `(foo-3-2)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, intersections, shapes, backgrounds, 
                scopes, positioning, fit, matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    varname/.style={rectangle, thin, inner sep=0.3ex,
        font=\ttfamily, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.35ex},
    vartype/.style={rectangle, text=red, thin, 
        inner sep=0.3ex, font=\ttfamily, text height=1.5ex, 
        text depth=0.35ex},
    struct/.style={draw, matrix of nodes, 
        column 1/.style={varname, anchor=base west},
        column 2/.style={vartype, anchor=base west}}
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (foo) 
{
    |(age)| age & int* \\
    height & float \\
    weight & float \\
};

\node[vartype, above=2ex of age.west, anchor=west] {Foo};
\node[vartype] (fooo) [draw=green, above=2ex of foo.north, anchor=west] {Foo};

\draw (age) -- (foo-3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]